# Throwing an object of a class defined within a class

Tags: c++, exception, try-catch

I'm reading chapter 16 so that I may begin my assignments for my C++ class. This section is on exception handling. I understand the concept behind a try / catch construct, however, one of the examples in the book is a bit confusing to me. I'm hoping for some explanation as to how this is working. The sample code is below:

```
// Includes, header guards, and namespace std...
class IntRange
{
 private:
  int intput;
  int lower;
  int upper;

 public: 
  // Exception class
  class OutOfRange { }; // This is exactly how it appears in the text.

  IntRange(int low, int high) { lower = low; upper = high; }
  int GetInput()
  {
    cin >> input;
    if (input < lower || input > upper)
      throw OutOfRange(); // <-- This is my question in particular. What is this?
    return input;
  }
};

// End header guard.

// Program entry point.

int main()
{
  IntRange range(5, 10)
  int userValue;

  cout << "Enter a value in the range 5 - 10: ";
  try
  {
    userValue = range.getInput();
    cout << "You entered " << userValue << endl;
  }
  catch (IntRange::OutOfRange) // <-- Again, what is this delcaration and how can
                               // this data type be defined when IntRange does not
                               // have a default constructor?
  {
    cout << "That value is out of range.\n";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

The code is exactly as it appears in the textbook, except I put some stuff on the same line in order to keep the question from becomming really long.

If you notice any errors, it's most likely a typo, but the most important points have been double-checked.

Comment: Startting out with C++ Early Objects - 7th Edition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  throw OutOfRange(); // <-- This is my question in particular. What is this?
```

This default constructs an object of `OutOfRange` then throws it.
Even if you do not define a methods in a class the compiler will automatically generate a couple for you one of these is the default constructor. Thus even if you don't specify a constructor there will be one there (Do a google on rule 3/5 for explanation of what methods are generated by the compiler).

```
catch (IntRange::OutOfRange) // <-- Again, what is this delcaration and how can
                             // this data type be defined when IntRange does not
                             // have a default constructor?
```

Here we are catching an object of type `IntRange::OutOfRange`. **Note**: we are **not** catching an object of `IntRange`. We are catching the class `OutOfRange` that happens to be defined inside the class `IntRange` (apart from where it is defined there is no other relationship).

Also note: Unless you disable it the compiler will automatically generate a copy constructor for all classes. Thus exceptions are usually copy constructed from the throw point to the catch point (its a tiny bit more complex). So your exception object must be copyable.

Also note it is best to catch exceptions by const reference:

```
catch (IntRange::OutOfRange const& e)
```

The avoids problems associated with slicing objects that are part of exception hierarchies.

Comment: OK, I see. To me it seemed like an object of OutOfRange could not be instantiated without first having an instance of an IntRange object. So if I am understanding you, it would be perfectly legal to delecare an object as such: IntRange::OutOfRange oor; And if it had members, I could interact with them without having ever created an object of IntRange?

Comment: @fhaddad78: Correct. There is no explicit relationship between object of these types. OutOfRange is a complete type in its own right and has no implicit references too IntRange

Answer (score 2):

```
 throw OutOfRange();
```

This creates a new instance of class `OutOfRange` and `throw`s it. Remember that you can also create an instance like this:

```
my_method( MyClass() );
```

instead of:

```
MyClass obj; 
my_method( obj );
```

Now:

```
catch (IntRange::OutOfRange)
```

`OutOfRange` is an *inner or nested class* of `IntRange`. See [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fcplr061.htm)

Comment: I just read that example on IBM's site. Thanks! Our book introduces new ideas and fails to provide any explanation. (=

Comment: see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) for some better books.

Answer (score 0):

They are creating a custom exception (as a class) called `OutOfRange` and throwing it.

This way, you can specifically catch an `OutOfRange` exception, this way:

```
try
{
    //do something
}
catch (OutOfRange o)
{
    //you know the input was out of range
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    //something else went wrong
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your `OutOfRange` class *belongs to* the `IntRange` class as a whole - it doesn't belong to any particular object of that class.

In order to use `OutOfRange` there's no requirement even for `IntRange` to actually be usable as a concrete class  , since `IntRange::OutOfRange` simply specifies the fully-qualified typename and not an object.

in C++, type names are only important at compile time; data type information (along with variable names and all sorts of other stuff like that in your code) is generally stripped out in its entirety by the compiler - data types only exist to help you write code and to do your debugging.

Comment: Thanks. Your explanation as well as a couple others explained what is going on very clearly.